# Argparse invalid argument parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I use following code for parsing arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("foo")
parser.add_argument("-b","--bar",
                    required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I call my script as:

```
python my.py --bar "this is strange" something
```

Unrecognized argument error is reported, but when I call my script this way:

```
python my.py --bar this isstrange
```

All is ok.

Its problem in my 4 lines of code or argparse has flawed parser?

Python 2.7.15

Bash

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on Python 2.7.12. You need to make a [mcve] including the import and the full error message.

Comment: Also what shell are you calling this from? I used Bash.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Python `3.6.7` or `2.7.15rc1`.

Comment: Are you sure you are using regular ASCII quotes? If you aren't, and are instead using typographic quotes `“` and `”`, then your argument list consists of `--bar`, `“this`, `is`, `strange”`, and `something`, rather than `--bar`, `this is strange`, and `something`, leading to an unexpectedly large number of arguments.

Comment: Good idea, but I am using correct quotes.

Comment: Knowing what the `unrecognized argument` was might have helped.  You can also check `sys.argv[1:]` to see what the parser has to work with.  `["--bar", "this is strange", "something"]` versus `["--bar", "this", "is" ,"strange", "something"]`